# download a csv file using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Im trying to create a local server that when visited, displays a download button and would download a CSV file that is already located in the directory.

Here's what I have in HTML already.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <style>
         p {
         color: green;
         }
      </style>
      <p> Click Download!
      <p>
         <a href="/transactions.csv" download="transactions">
         <button type="button">Download</button>
         </a>
   </body>
</html>
```

When this is loaded onto the local server, an HTML page is downloaded rather than the CSV file. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If possible you should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Edit your question and add what you have done in node.js so far. Your question is not clear if you need help on the frontend or the backend or ... Please improve your question where whe should help you.

Comment: Are you testing the HTML through a web server or directly opening it locally from the file system (file:// protocol)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express.js you can try to return CSV as a response

```
const path = path.join(__dirname, './transactions.csv') // CSV file location

    response.download(path), err => {
          if(err) {
            // error handler
          }
        })
```

your button

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/download/transactions">
         <button type="button">Download</button>
         </a>
```